# Generic method that get random object and returns it

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a generic "Login" method that will get a random object and should return this object.

```
 public class LoginPageOne : BasePage
    {      
        public LoginPageOne(Browser browser)
            : base(browser)
        {
         CheckPageErrors(UserName, page);
        }

        public PianoBar_Obj1 Login(Browser browser, IUser username)
        {
            //Do something
            return new PianoBar_Obj1 (browser);
        }     
    }

    public class LoginPageTwo : BasePage
    {      
        public LoginPageTwo (Browser browser)
            : base(browser)
        {
            CheckPageErrors(UserName, page);
        }

        public PianoBar_Obj2 Login(Browser browser, IUser username)
        {
            //Do something
            return new PianoBar_Obj2 (browser);
        }     
    }

public BasePage(Browser browser)
    : base(browser)
{
    browser.BrowserHelper.RunJavascriptOverideLogs();
}
```

I want to create only one "Login" generic method that will be able to get any object type, please note that the implementation of this method is the same except the return type.
something like:

```
 public T Login(T object,Browser browser, IUser username)
    {
    // Do something`
     return new T();
    }
```

Comment: Please show  the `BasePage`? and how do you want to use `Login` method?

Comment: " please note that the implementation of this method is the same except the return type" - no, it's not. Because you're trying to call a *parameterless* constructor in your generic method, whereas in the concrete methods you're passing in `browser`. A generic type can be constrained to have a parameterless constructor, but it can't be constrained to have a constructor with a particular signature. (It's not clear to me why you've got an initial `T object` parameter, either.) Please could you clarify your question?

Comment: er-esho - I've added the BasePage, the way that i want to use the Login method:                                                                                         
PianoBar_Obj2  = loginPage.Login(_browser, _config.Users.JewelersUsers.Agent);                                               PianoBar_Obj1  = loginPage.Login(_browser, _config.Users.JewelersUsers.Agent);

Comment: So `loginPage` is instance of `LoginPageOne` or `LoginPageTwo` ?

Comment: if its instance of `LoginPageOne` then you are accessing `Login` method inside `LoginPageOne` and if its instance of `LoginPageTwo` then you are accessing method inside `LoginPageTwo` so how generic will work in your case?

Comment: Why would you need to pass a object of type `T` to your Login method if all it should do is creating a new object of type `T`? The signature of your Login method doesn't make a whole lotta sense to me...

Answer (score 2):

```
public T Login<T>()
  where T: class, new()
{
  return new T();
}
```

To call this from code with PianoBar_Obj2, simply call it as follows:

```
return Login<PianoBar_Obj2>();
```

Comment: Why having method arguments at all if they are not going to be used?

Comment: Good question. The arguments aren't used so they aren't meaningful but who knows... we don't know the full design.

Comment: It looks exactly what I want, but how I call this method in case my T input is "PianoBar_Obj2"?

Comment: @noam-igor-veronin, I removed the parameters that weren't being used. If you're just wanting to specify the type, you can simply pass the type as the generic parameter. I have changed the answer to reflect what I now think you really want. Also, if you want to be extra fancy, you can add an interface to the where clause where T: ISomeInterface, new(). This will allow you to use the object you just receive in a strongly typed way. (If you need those parameters back, just let me know.)